# How to get email address of list of users in Jenkins variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Lets say I have Global variable in Jenkins as below. these are actual user names of Jenkins.

`Notify_Users = anne,raw,thoms,nandy`

What I need is, get email addresses of these users from my pipeline script as I have correctly put their email addresses in each user properties under Manage user section in Jenkins.

The reason is I don't want to hard code users's email addresses in my Jenkinsfile. also I want to use this existing variable Notify_Users without creating new variable with email addresses, because we already use this variable for some other reason.

Since I'm very new for programming therefore couldn't find any point that I can start work on this. anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

In Jenkins you could have a look on [hudson.model.User class](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/User.html).

> [public static User getById(String id, boolean create)](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/User.html#getById-java.lang.String-boolean-)

With this you probably could

```
User u = User.getById(id, false)
def email = u.getProperty(Mailer.UserProperty.class)
print email.getAddress()
```